# PartialViews Messing With Eachother

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, postback, partial-views

I have the following _Layout.cshtml page that has a bunch of `@Html.Action()` calls to several partial views.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><div class="logo"><p>fisharwe</p><span class="greenText float-right">:</span></div></a>
        <div class="searchBar">
            @Html.Action("Search", "Item")
        </div>
        <div id="hearGreenBar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div id="help">
            <div id="allHelpContent">
                <span id="helpIcon"></span> <span id="helpTitle">help</span> <span id="helpArrow"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="userPanel">
            @if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <div id="loginForm">@Html.Action("Login", "User")</div>
                <div id="registerForm">@Html.Action("Register", "User")</div>
                <hr class="greyLine" />

                <div id="recentlyViewedItems">
                    <div id="recentItemsTitle">
                        <span class="recentItemsIcon"></span><span class="theRecentTitle">Recently Viewed</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="userInfoSummary">@Html.Action("Summary", "User")</div>
            } 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the top you can see the `@Html.Action("Seach", "Item")` call which renders a search bar and allows users to search for items/categories/sub-categories...etc. I got this working now, but it generated a new problem! When the user searches for something, and the results are rendered, the `Login` and `Register` partials in the sidebar (userPanel) are displaying validation errors such as "Email cannot be empty". I understand that the View is rendered regardless of what partial posted back but there has to be a way to prevent that from happening... Do I have to get rid of partials and render everything into the _Layout.cshtml page? But in that case I need to make this page typed which will cause yet another issue... So what can be done? I'm open to any suggestions...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have different forms for the search and what is in the "userPanel"?. You may want to make sure your search is doing a get and not a post.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YourController", FormMethod.Get))
```

Comment: @B Z: `@Html.Action("Login", "User")` and `@Html.Action("Register", "User")`, both of which contain forms.

Comment: Does your search also have a form? See my updated answer, check you are doing a get and not a post

Comment: @B Z: Actually yes it does contain a form and it's doing a post not a get. I guess now that I changed the name of the method, GET would be more appropriate. Will give it a try :)